# How to know the relationship among the superconducitng phase , the gap, and the gapless edge states?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

I feel puzzled about how to decide whether a material is in the superconducting phase, whether the gap can decide the superconducting phase, and whether there exists the gapless edge states.